# How can values in the Alfresco pooled tasks table be changed?

Tags: alfresco

I would like to change the data that is displayed in one of the Pooled Tasks
columns. It's not clear where does that data comes from.
For example, in my pooled-tasks-todo-dashlet.jsp file it has this section:

```
<%-- Status column --%>
<a:column id="col6" style="padding:2px;text-align:left">
<f:facet name="header">
<a:sortLink id="col6-sort" label="#{msg.status}" value="bpm:status" styleClass="header"/>
</f:facet>
<h:outputText id="col6-txt" value="#{r['bpm:status']}" />
</a:column>
```

Where is the status value "#{r['bpm:status']}"  stored? 
How do you add a new value that is not already defined?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The object #{r} is the current node object iterated over the Alfresco JSF component  [a:richList](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/RichList). The value of this component is set by a JSF Bean, thus if you want to add a new property to #{r} I think the better way is by adding it in the Java bean that populates the richlist.

If you are only interested in modifying the values of the property jbpm:status, I guess it is bpm engine specific (it can be either jbpm or activity).

Answer (score 0):

I have done it in one of my project.
If you observe jsp page in rich list tag you will find this

value="#{WorkflowBean.pooledTasks}
 The bean which populate the rich list is workflowBean
 which points to this class org.alfresco.web.bean.workflow.WorkflowBean
 and this API get called when dashlet is open
 List getPooledTasks()

It populates the pooledTask List then just like for loop we iterate the nodes one by one with r pointing to current workflow node.